# Error: 104 Failed to Obtain Version Information from CRPE32.dll - GetCRPEVersion

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports-xi, delphi-xe3

I did a search and cannot find another question like this one. I'm getting this error with Delphi XE2 and Delphi XE3. I'm using Crystal Reports XI R1. I'm not sure why Delphi would care about the version, the error would need to be during initialization of crpe32.dll. I'm upgrading a Delphi 2006 app to XE3. Very little work required - the only barrier between me and success s this DLL error. Any insight would be appreciated. Many TIAs !

Best regards,
Brian

Comment: I'm pretty sure Delphi doesn't really care about the version of this third party DLL. Maybe the vendor does?

Comment: Oh, from your old question it seems you're using ActiveX. It doesn't work.  I put about 20 hours into getting it to work, then I read on the SAP forums that it doesn't even run properly in VisualBasic 6 or anywhere else, other than using their new .Net bindings from within VB.net or C#.net.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because on my machine I forgot to install Crystal Reports. I recently installed Win10 and if Crystal Reports was not installed, it gave me this error. Hope it helps!